# I have this message on a Service Apache "Internal Server Error"

Tags: apache

I have this message on a Service Apache
**
Internal Server Error**
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request ...

After having associated a domain to Godaddy, I enter the URL through the browser and I get that message
I hope to be able to view the index.html file located in the root of the project

Comment: Hi, welcome. Your question fits better on [Serverfault](https://serverfault.com)

Comment: The http 500 status you get from the http server indicates exactly what it says: an _internal_ error. For privacy and security reasons the actual issue is _not_ mentioned, since that would be visible for everyone accessing that server. Instead you need to take a look into the server's error log file. That is where you can simply read what the actual issue is.